# Changing Design Configuration Settings Aren't Reflected on Frontend

Tags: magento2, theme

As you can see below, I have changed the footer text information but on the frontend it still shows the old footer text.

New Footer
[image]

Website Footer
[image]

Steps I have taken so far to try to fix this:

- Deleted all contents in pub/static folder
- Deleted all contents in var_view_preprocessed folder
- Ran php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy command
- Disabled all magento caching/Flushed and Cleaned caches
- Set to developer mode and then back to production mode

Information about my website:

- Using Magento 2.1.6
- installed through github clone

I'm completely frustrated and lost with this issue. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These code snippets solve the most of my issues (mainly similar to yours):

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
mage cache:flush &
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:static-content:deploy;
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```

Comment: All that did for me was give me this error message:

[Exception]
  Warning: ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /var/www
  /html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/EntityAbstract.php on line 15
  2